# Restrict authors to seeing ONLY their media files

Tags: uploads

I'd like to restrict authors ability to see files uploaded by other users because this causes no end of trouble, since they can change captions etc.

I tried this code from here [How to hide media uploads by other users in the Media menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30308/how-to-hide-media-uploads-by-other-users-in-the-media-menu)

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','users_own_attachments');
function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) {

    global $current_user, $pagenow;

    if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
        return;

    if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow )
        return;

    if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') )
        $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->id );

    return;
}
```

This only works on the media screen, not when you select a file on a post to actually upload.

I also tried the second solution, but it's causing issues with my autocomplete search function and I can't figure out why.

Is there a way to stop authors seeing others files when they're making a post?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but maybe you can just extend the `$pagenow` check?

Instead of …

```
if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow )
```

… try …

```
if( ! in_array( $pagenow, array ( 'upload.php', 'post-new.php', 'post.php' ) ) )
```

That should cover the post editor screens too.

Comment: Tested that, doesn't work unfortunately.